# How to 'append' function variables using the URL and a question about Array's

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The first question is how to run a function using the URL, I have the following function:

```
function do_curl($start_index,$stop_index){

    // Do query here to get all pages with ids between start index and stop index

    $query = "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx >= $start_index and xxx <= $stop_index";
```

Now when I'm trying to do curl.php?start_index=0&stop_index=2 this is not working but when i delete the function and WHERE idnum = 1 it is working.

Now the second question is how 'compile' all the fields from the rows to arrays? I have the current code:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM fanpages";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $fanpages_query = '\'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id'].'\', ';
    echo $fanpages_query;    
}


$fanpages = array($fanpages_query);
$fanpages_count = count($fanpages);
echo $fanpages_count;
```

echo $fanpages_query; returning

```
'http://graph.facebook.com/AAAAAA', 'http://graph.facebook.com/BBBBBBB', 'http://graph.facebook.com/CCCCCCCC',
```

(I don't have an idea how to do it in a different way, also when im doing it in such a way i can't delete the final comma which will return PHP-error.)

echo $fanpages_count; returns 1 and like you can see i have 3 there.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Are you storing the $_GET['start_index'] and stop_index in variables before passing them to the query in do_curl? And are you returning anything from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a function call to do the query

```
function do_curl($start_index, $stop_index){
    ...
}

$fanpages = do_curl($_GET['start_index'], $_GET['stop_index']);
```

For your second question, you can use arrays and the implode function to insert commas:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $fanpages_query[] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id'];  
}
return $fanpages_query;
```

Then use implode to print them out:

```
echo implode(',', $fanpages);
```

The whole code:

```
function do_curl($start_index = 0, $stop_index = null) {

    $queryIfThereIsNoStartIndex = '';
    $queryIFThereIsNoStopIndex = '';
    $queryIfBothStartAndStopIndexAreMissing = '';

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $fanpages_query[] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id'];  
    }
    return $fanpages_query;
}

$fanpages = do_curl($_GET['start_index'], $_GET['stop_index']);
$fanpages_count = count($fanpages);
echo implode(',', $fanpages);
```

And you should totally use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) for escaping the values you add to the query.

Comment: in do_curl you also need to use mysql_real_escape_string <http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string> otherwise you will have a serious security hole.

Comment: @glass Yeah, I was waiting for someone to say that, record is at 12 seconds though

Comment: Thanks but is till don't get it, you didnt explained how to insert the arrays to $fanpages = array(Whats here?);
The second thing is even when the Query is not using the start_index and stop_index variables i still see only a blank page cause i thing all the echo's and stuff are inside this function and i need to access it somehow.

Comment: @rico `$fanpages` will come from the array that is returned by `do_curl` in the first code block. My 2nd code block should be inside `do_curl`.

Comment: @rico I updated my answer to combine the code blocks. For your follow-up question, if the page is blank then the query did not return any results. You should provide default values for the indexes.

Comment: Thank you but for some weird reason i get those errors for every thing i want to resolve from the graph (it was working before this code) : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48, i mean the json_decode function isn't working, so must of the chances the arrays are not parsed correctly, any suggestions buddy?
EDIT: When I'm trying 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id']; without the \' the middle one is working (there are three).

Comment: @rico Well I just answered your original questions. Any follow-ups should be posted as a different question, don't you think?

Comment: well yea buddy, thanks, just please tell me if you can if the arrays are parsed like it needs to ('http//...', 'fsdfsdfsdf', '...');

Comment: @rico Hmmm, I removed the `\'` in the URLs in my code, my bad. Now I'm not sure what you do to the `$fanpages` array after getting it, so I don't really know what happens next. Likely, you need to use somnething like: `foreach($fanpages as $fanpage) { $data = file_get_contents($fanpage); }`